# How to modify /usr/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-sensor.hwdb to correct screen rotation in tablet mode?

Tags: systemd, chrome-book, sensors

OS: Debian 11

`udev` comes with a configuration file `/usr/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-sensor.hwdb` in which it states that:

```
# Allowed properties are:
#    ACCEL_MOUNT_MATRIX=<matrix>
#    PROXIMITY_NEAR_LEVEL=<value>
#
# where <matrix> is a mount-matrix in the format specified in the IIO
# subsystem[1]. The default, when unset, is equivalent to:
#   ACCEL_MOUNT_MATRIX=1, 0, 0; 0, 1, 0; 0, 0, 1
# eg. the identity matrix,
# and <value> is an integer value above which an object is considered
# close by a proximity sensor:
#   PROXIMITY_NEAR_LEVEL=100
#
# [1]: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=dfc57732ad38f93ae6232a3b4e64fd077383a0f1
#
# Note for devices where the display (LCD panel) is mounted non upright
# in the device's casing, e.g. mounted upside-down or 90 degree rotated,
# the ACCEL_MOUNT_MATRIX should be such that the x and y axis matches the
# x and y axis of the display, not those of the casing, so that desktop
# environments using the accelerometer data for rotation will e.g.
# automatically flip their output for an upside-down display when the device
# is held upright.
#
#    ACCEL_LOCATION=<location>
#
# where <location> is the location of the sensor. This value could be 'base'
# or 'display'. The default, when unset, is equivalent to:
#    ACCEL_LOCATION=display
```

with such examples as

```
#########################################
# Google Chromebooks
#########################################
sensor:modalias:platform:cros-ec-accel:dmi:*:svnGOOGLE:*
 ACCEL_MOUNT_MATRIX=-1, 0, 0; 0, -1, 0; 0, 0, -1
```

I have a Pixelbook running Debian 11 on which the screen in tablet mode is always rotated 180 degrees (in both portrait and profile mode). I figure if I apply a rotation matrix that would rotate the screen 180 degrees around the z-axis, i..e. [ -1 0 0; 0 -1, 0; 0 0 1] in a /etc/udev/hwdb.d file it would fix the problem. But this effort so far changes nothing. Could it be because the rotation matrix is wrong?

Another wrinkle is that Pixelbook has 2 accelerometers, one in the lid, and one in the base. Their `modalias` is `cros-ec-accel`, as in the example, but in `sysfs` they are also appended with `.N.auto`, where `N` is just a number that changes on each boot. Could it be that that the sensor is incorrectly or insufficiently referred to in the example above? I tried `sensor:modalias:platform:cros-ec-accel.*:dmi:*:svnGOOGLE:pnEve*` and adding `ACCEL_LOCATION=<lid|base>` to no avail.